# solr on rasperry pi 2 - bin/solr create core causing connection refused error

Tags: ubuntu, solr, server, raspberry-pi

I installed **solr** on **Ubuntu trusty** on **Raspberry Pi 2**.

I can start the server and visit the admin page

```
http://localhost:8983/solr
```

When I try to create a new core using

```
bin/solr create -c testcore
```

however I get:

> INFO  - 2016-03-01 03:23:41.179;
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector; I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException)
>   caught when processing request to {}-> http://localhost:8983: The target server failed to respond
>
> INFO  - 2016-03-01 03:23:41.196; org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector; Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8983
>   ERROR: Connection refused

The Ubuntu trusty I have on my Pi is fairly sparse as far as far as software goes, so I'm not sure if there is some package I am missing. I mention this because this same setup works fine on my laptop which is running Ubuntu trusty, ie I can create cores.

I'm somewhat of a beginner regarding **solr** and servers, so I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the server never came up fully.   Find the `solr.log` and troubleshoot.

(Hint, a Rπ2 only has 1Gb memory.   Solr by default may be trying to launch with a 512mb heap. )